# How to define in an API, since which version a path/parameter is supported

Tags: swagger, openapi

We have an growing swagger API/openAPI and for documenting changes we like to document on a path or parameter (and perhaps definition) since which version of the API it is available.

The swagger specification knows the `info.version` field, but on `paths` or `parameters` I could not find something refering to this version.

Perhaps [vendor extensions](http://swagger.io/specification/#vendorExtensions) beginning with a `x-...` like `x-since` might be helpful. At least validation does not fail using them.

But is there perhaps any existing implementation for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing attribute in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 spec to meet your need so you should go with vendor extensions (x-since, x-created-on, x-created-by, etc)